# Pass the variable with jq that includes spaces

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to create a variable using jq, let's say, for example:

```
firstName=($(curl -s https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item | jq -r '.items[].firstName'))
```

The result I expected is "C. Ronaldo" but it gave me only "C." How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `.items[0]` and command substitution instead of `($(...))` which is an array and is a subject to word-splitting, hence just the `C.`:

```
$ var=$(curl -s 'https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/api/fut/item' | jq -r '.items[0].firstName')
$ echo "$var"
C. Ronaldo
```